# iOS 14 safari canPlayType('audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"') returns ""

Tags: mp3, ios14

In my webapplication before I play audio I check with canPlayType() if the format is supported. Since iOS 14 mp3 audio files do not return a valid response.

the check [HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType)('audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"') returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code:

```
let audio = [
'audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"',
'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"',
'audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"',
'audio/wav; codecs="1"',
'audio/webm; codecs="vorbis"',
'audio/x-flv',
'audio/mpeg;']

let elmAudio = document.createElement('audio');

for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++)
{
   let bSupports = elmAudio.canPlayType(audio[i]);
   console.log("canPlay", audio[i], bSupports);
}
```

(see https://jsfiddle.net/0zr9pms8/4/)
I validated that the check without the codecs part gives a correct return value on iOS14.

HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;')